# Crystal report don't display any data

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I use Crystal report in my c# application, this is the code i use:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
    {
        case "FicheArticle":
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand ficheCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CodeArticle, LibArticleFr, InfomationsDetaille, StockActuel FROM Article WHERE CodeArticle = @code", con);
            ficheCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code",Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value));

            DataSet ficheDs = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(ficheCmd);
            dscmd.Fill(ficheDs, "Article");

            CrystalReport7 objRpt7 = new CrystalReport7();
            objRpt7.SetDataSource(ficheDs);
            crystalReportViewer7.ReportSource = objRpt7;
            crystalReportViewer7.Refresh();
            con.Close();
            break;
    }
}
```

The query is correct because i tested it before but the Crystal report don't show anything. So where is the error??

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: There is no error but the report is displaying blank with no data

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and checked that `ficheDs` indeed contains data? How did you setup your data inside CR? Are you sure that the schema matches? - It's impossible to tell from this.

Comment: BTW: please use `using` on things like `con`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, the datasource of the report is linked to other table than

Article table, and it is not set in the code. So the tables of the datasource

must be the same in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
objRpt7.SetDataSource(ficheDs);
crystalReportViewer7.ReportSource = objRpt7;
```

Keep breakpoints and find the values of the dataset.

```
SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(ficheCmd);
```

Also check the query stored in `ficheCmd` , run as a new query and find the result of the query.

Answer (score -1):

```
 MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT invoive.per_ID,person.per_type,person.per_name,person.per_mobile,
                    invoive.INV_date,invoive.INV_no,invoive.INV_details,invoive.INV_Dr,invoive.INV_cr
                    FROM `invoive` INNER JOIN person ON invoive.per_ID = person.per_ID  WHERE 
                    invoive.INV_date BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "' AND invoive.per_ID ='" + textEdit1.Text + "' ORDER BY invoive.INV_date", con);
                    DataSet dst = new DataSet();
                    sda.Fill(dst, "invoive");
                    cryrptz1.Load(@"E:\Claasified\Company\FactoryManager\FactoryManager\CrystalReport6.rpt");
                    cryrptz1.SetDataSource(dst);crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrptz1;
                    int ii = dst.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

                    if (ii == 0)
                    {
                        // Here You can Send
                    }
```